# Getting 'expected { Object (message, detail) } to have property 'count' error in API testing using cypress

Tags: rest, cypress, web-api-testing

I want to assert the total count received from the response.

This is my code:

```
cy.request({
        method:'GET',
        url:'https://ibis-qa.droicelabs.us/api/practice/orders/?q=&limit=100',
        failOnStatusCode: false,
        headers:{
            accept: "application/json"
        }
    }).then(Response => {
        let body = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Response.body))
        cy.log(body)
        expect(body).has.property('count','27')
   })
```

and this is the error that I have got

[image]

[image: Response body]

Comment: Does your response body has the property count? . You can check this by logging the response body `cy.log(JSON.stringify(Response.body))`

Comment: Yes, the response body has the property count

Comment: Your request is not properly authorised. You need to add an authorization header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use

```js
expect(body).has.property('count', 27)
```

as the value is a number

(see screen-shot, there are no quotes around `27`)

---

You are not getting the JSON response you think you should have.

If go to the URL in the browser, I get this

```js
{"message":"field required","detail":[{"loc":["header","authorization"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

which is what is partially shown in the screenshot of the error message.

This is an **error response** from the server, and it means your request is not correct.

Comment: Not in my test, what do you get with `console.log(body.count)`?

Comment: Please write detailed answare

Comment: What do you want to know? The `console.log(body.count)` is to see what you are actually receiving.

Comment: console.log(body.count). it's through the same error and it will not print anything. And I think you can get that error because API requests need to login authentication.

Comment: Indeed, that's what the screenshot indicates. Do you know how to authorize? It will be specific to the site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236886/discussion-between-krupal-vaghasiya-and-vispo).

Answer (score 1):

Then you can directly use the assertion like this. You don't need to parse or stringify.

```js
expect(Response.body).to.have.property('count',27)
```

You can check this example from the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Send-a-POST-request-with-a-JSON-body).

Comment: This is not working and through the same error.

Comment: it should be `to.have`. I have updated my  answer

Comment: `has` and `to.have` are the same thing.

Comment: May be. But I was looking into the chai docs and I couldn't find any `has` there - https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_property

Comment: I have also tried this but have not succed.

Comment: Please remove everything else from the response section except `expect(Response.body).to.have.property('count',27)`. And also please make sure you save the file and try again. This should work.

Comment: @Alapan found it [here}(https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/)

Comment: @Alapan It is not working I have tried all possible ways. Please check I have attached a screenshot of your suggestion.[ibb.co/54SZMSR]

Comment: From you error it seems like you're not gettin count in your response body. Can you log this and check -`cy.log(Response.body.count)` ?

Comment: Through the same error. And I think I can get that error because API requests need to login authentication